# Как можно сверстать шапку с скошенными краями?

Tags: вёрстка, веб-программирование, frontend

Каким образом можно реализовать скошенные края у блока без использования картинок.
Красными линиями показаны пределы блока container.

**Пример:**

[image: Пример]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
#outer,
#block {
  color: #fff;
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
#content {
  transform: skewX(30deg);
}
#block {
  background: blue;
}
#outer {
  transform: skewX(-30deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="block">
    <div id="content">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```